# file with a column value does not retain the value when copied or moved to a similar library

Tags: 2010, column, move

I have a simple requirement of a single file editing and then moved (I am fine with moving it manually) to a secondary library for archive.

The original Doc library have a url field that is not needed in the second destination library. The destination library has a date field that needs to be filled in (again, I am fine with filling it manually, it can be either today's date or a manual date).

When the original file is ready to be moved (or copied) from the original library to the destination library I use Content and Structure. Copy or Move gives me the same result: the file keeps the URL field and does not show  the date field in the properties. The date field is mandatory in the second list.

Is this normal behaviour? How can I move/copy retaining metadata (especially version) and adding this date field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using Content and Structure, while moving the file from one library to another library it will retain the all the properties and structure, make sure both libraries has all the columns including file url and date field which you have mentioned.

But,
In source library from where file is being moved, you can hide the date column in library settings.
In destination library where file is being moved to, you can hide the file url column in library settings.

using this way all the data version everything will be retained.

Comment: is there something I can do to automate this easy process? I have tried a workflow (2010) but I could not find the action 'move file'

Comment: Not sure whether you can move file with properties and version with SharePoint inbuilt function, but you can write custom code to move the files with properties and version history,